# want to copy data from one table to another with added 2 new columns in oracle

Tags: oracle11g

i have a query in mysql

```
insert into a_archive ( select * , "Zuned Ahmed" as archivedBy from B);
```

The above query executing fine in mysql, this does not support in oracle.

please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this one instead:

```
insert into a_archive 
select b.* , 'Zuned Ahmed' as archivedBy from B b
```

Explanation:

When using Oracle database:

1- To specify literal strings, single quotes `''` are used. Double quotes `""` serve a different purpose.

2- If `*` is specified without being prefixed with an alias, no other column is allowed. Otherwise, `*` must be prefixed with the table alias.

3- `Insert ... Select ...` statements follow exactly the same syntax as given above; using braces is not allowed.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi., Reza.. when i try to implement the same in "MERGE INTO" it seems not working.. can u pls give me example for "MERGE INTO".

Comment: @Wannacoffee for example consider this: `merge into a_archive a using B b on (a.x = b.x) when matched then update set a.n = b.name when not matched then insert (n) values('Zuned Ahmed')`.